# Angular 16 Email validation error using pattern

Tags: angular

forms

public repo: https://github.com/anoop-mobi/template-drivan-email-pattern

Email Validation using the pattern is throwing error on console

i have Installed fresh angular 16 to check it. in the given public repo you can see the code

[image: Error]

[image: component.ts]

[image: component.html]

Console error

```
Pattern attribute value ^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$ is not a valid regular expression
```

complete error
Pattern attribute value ^[a-z0-9.*%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught "SyntaxError": Invalid regular expression: /^[a-z0-9.*%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/v: Invalid character in character class

Comment: Try to use this email regex

const emailRegEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i;

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Include all relevant code here in the question, as a [mcve]. Links can break, and linked content can change (especially on github!), making the question useless for others with similar problems. It may also be too much code if you have to link to a whole repository. Make it easy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue related to recent changes in the browsers: [It is now recommended](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/7908) that browsers use the `v` flag on regex patterns.

Chrome has switched to this behavior [in M114](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5149507107422208).

So you need to make your regex compatible with that. In the case of your regex, you'll need to escape the dash :

```
^[a-z0-9._%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.\-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$
```